# Jquery dialog only opening once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

All-
I know this has been asked, but the previous solutions don't seem to apply to my situation.

I have a simple table with a number of records in each row, with the final column being a delete hyperlink. I'm trying to use the dialog to pop up and confirm delete. This works perfectly if I use explicit names of the div where the dialog is (I position it exactly one div above the div where the table is). I use a destroy first which seems to solve the "only opens once" problem, as long as as I name the dialog div. I'm trying to universalize the code, so I'd rather get away from explicitly naming the div where the dialog will live, but rather refer to the prev div. This works the first time, but subsequent clicks do not:

```
<code>
   $(".deleteLinkDiag a").livequery('click',function() {

    var myParent = $(this).parents("div:eq(0)"); //container div to be replaced
    var myDiag   = $(myParent).prev("div");     //one div before container div
    var urlLoad = $(this).attr("href");
    $(myDiag).dialog('destroy');
    $(myDiag).dialog({ 
            bgiframe: true,
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            buttons: {
                    "Confirmz":function() 
                    { 
                        myParent.load(urlLoad, function() { });
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                     },
                    Cancel: function() 
                    {  
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
            },
            //close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('destroy');}
      });
     $(myDiag).dialog('open');
return false;
});
</code>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `var myDiag   = $(myParent).prev("div");` always select a different div for each button, or does it always select the same div?

Comment: Can you upload an example somewhere that demonstrates how this isn't working for you? I'm finding it difficult to visualise

Comment: Sure thing: http://163.150.129.104/j/index.php

So the idea would be, there's two datatables, each with a unique delete column for each row, and each with a different dialog box right before the table div. Works popping up dialog the first time, but not after that. If I put the name of the class in dialog("open"), it works fine, but I want to be able to target just one div without making multiple copies of this function.

Comment: Just to answer dcneiner's question: myDiag selects the correct div the first time. All subsequent times that the link is clicked it returns undefined. My guess would be that through the course of opening the dialog the div's position in the DOM is actually moved, so it's no longer in "prev" or "prevAll". The strange thing is that I'm running destroy on close, so that should set the div back to it's previous position, enabling me to grab it with prev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKay, so hopefully this will help someone down the road. I actually had two problems going on:

1. If you dont' destroy the dialog(), then it doesn't really exist in the DOM under the old name. That's why it was always undefined the second time through.
2. Even if you DO destroy the dialog, you still can't find it. That's because when dialog *theoretically* returns it to pre-init state, it does so by dropping it at the bottom of the DOM right before the body tag. So, it's no longer in "prev" , or "prevAll".

I got around this by just setting the name of the dialog box to be the same as the calling div, appended with "Diag". Then I can track it no matter where jquery puts it. Whew.

```
$(".deleteLinkDiag a").livequery('click',function() {
            var urlLoad = $(this).attr("href");
            var myParent = $(this).parents("div:eq(0)"); //container div to be replaced
            var myDiag = myParent.attr('id') + 'Diag';
            $("#" + myDiag).dialog({
                    bgiframe: true,
                            resizable: false,
                            height:140,
                            modal: true,
                            autoOpen: false,
                            overlay: {
                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                    opacity: 0.5
                            },
                    buttons: {
                                    "Confirm":function()
                                    {
                                            myParent.load(urlLoad, function() { });
                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                     },
                                    Cancel: function()
                                    {
                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                              },
                    close: function(ev, ui) {
                            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    }
      });
     $("#" + myDiag).dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that the problem lies in the fact that the actual dialog div isn't actually being selected correctly. And that (as far as I'm understanding the situation) stems from a bigger problem of wrong requirements on your part.

If you want to reference a specific div, then you should reference that specific div. Yet, I hear you saying you want to reference a specific div (which is literally the only div which is used as a dialog) at the same time that you say you're afraid to reference that div by an ID.

Basically, if there is only one div that's used as the dialog, then accept that and just call that div a name:

```
<div id="dialog"/>
```

.

```
myDiag = $('#dialog');
```

This way there is no confusion on if you are selecting the correct div.

However, if what I said is not an option for some reason, then you can set break points in firebug at the point where you assign `myDiag` so that you can see what `myDiag` actually is at execution time.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The reason that I don't want to reference a specific div by ID is because I want to be able to use this function generically on multiple pages (and maybe even with multiple sets of delete buttons on the same page), so the div id could change. I'll try your suggestion with Firebug.