# Jquery: dialog box only shows once per click

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I have a series of "links & divs" like these:

```
<a class="pop" href="popup.asp?PD=12>Hotel XXX</a>
<div class="details" title="Hotel XXX"></div>

<a class="pop" href="popup.asp?PD=52>Hotel YYY</a>
<div class="details" title="Hotel YYY"></div>

...
```

I'm using the following javascript, and it works very nice except the fact that I can open the dialog only once per click

```
$('.pop').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).next('div.details').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
    modal: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 500
});
})
```

I read somewhere that I have to use the "autoOpen: false" feature, but I have no idea on where to put this...

Please, can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should look at [This question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794243/jquery-dialog-only-opening-once). It looks very similar

Comment: If it can help, when I try to display something I'm sure that exists (like the title of the div), I get "undefined": like this:

$('.pop').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).next('div.details').attr('title'));
  })

Answer (score 1):

Building upon what Jonathan did and using something a little closer to your original click function, this should do the trick.

```
$(function(){

  $(".details").dialog({
    autoOpen:false
  });

  $('.pop').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('div.details').html("").load($(this).attr('href')).dialog('open');
  })

});
```

By declaring the dialog earlier and with `autoOpen:false` we're setting it up but not displaying the dialog. You can then call `dialog('open')` on the element with the dialog functionality and have it open.

Answer (score 0):

Tested, and works: http://jsbin.com/ikate

I separated the initialization of the dialog from the click event of the links. The click event merely finds its corresponding dialog, and opens it.

```
$(function(){

  $(".details").dialog({
    autoOpen:false
  });

  $("a.pop").each(function(i,o){
    $(this).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".details:eq("+i+")").html("Dialog " + i).dialog('open');    
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: this does not fix his problem: try to open a dialog by clicking on the text, close it, and try to reopen the same dialog. Doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jonathan: I tried your code but a click on the same link opens the dialog again... If I have N pairs of "a/div" groups, clicking N times on the same link opens N dialog boxes
The most strange thing is that each of these dialog opens with a different title (the first with "Hotel XXX", the second with "Hotel YYY", etc..)